# Can Clojure/Lisp macros be used to implement this lambda syntax?

Tags: syntax, clojure, macros, lambda, nested-function

```
((#(%a %b') {a:1 b:2}) {a:3 b:4}) -> (1 4)
```

In JavaScript would be the same as:

```
(function(x){ return function(y){ return [x.a,y.b]; }})({a:1,b:2})({a:3,b:4});
Output: [1,4]
```

So, in other words, a short syntax for lambdas which (differently from Clojure's current implementation) allows nested functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly (though I have given it my best guess). Could you add some sample input and output to clarify?

Comment: I couldn't make what the clojure example syntax is about. Could you please explain .. like what does #(%a %b') evaluates to?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to do it with straight Clojure code without any macros (i.e. equivalent to the JavaScript version) then you just want:

```
(((fn [x] (fn [y] (list (:a x) (:b y)))) {:a 1 :b 2}) {:a 3 :b 4}) 
=> (1 4)
```

You could also do this with macros providing you choose a different form other than `#()` for the actual macro identifier, e.g. you could do:

```
(((my-lambda %a %b) {:a 1 :b 2}) {:a 3 :b 4}) 
=> (1 4)
```

(p.s. I fixed the map keywords from the orginival question, `a:1` won't work.....)

The approach would be:

- Create a macro called `my-lambda`
- Have this macro examine the symbols that it is passed and convert them to keyword lookups against auto-generated symbols
- Output code for a function using the auto-generated symbols like: `(fn [sym1] (fn [sym2](list (:a sym1) (:b sym2))))`

This approach would work perfectly fine with nested functions. The important thing to know with Clojure lambdas is that  `(fn [...] ...)` can nest, but `#(...)` cannot (since it would otherwise cause ambiguities with the function parameters).

You can't override the `#()` syntax directly because Clojure doesn't yet support reader macros. I actually think this is a good thing - allowing arbitrary redefinitions of syntax is likely to lead to some people writing pretty unmaintainable code for no obvious benefit (saving a few characters of typing but suffering reduced readability/code comprehension is *not* a benefit in my view).

I'd like to think that anywhere I see `#()` in Clojure code I know it is a regular anonymous function, and not have to worry about the possibility that someone has redefined it to do something strange.

Answer (score 2):

the anonymous reader macro `#( )` syntax does not allow nested anonymous functions because it would be unclear which function a given argument `%2` would correspond to. People have suggested ways of resolving the ambiguity on the mailing list, and the consensus has been that the `(fn [arg] ...)` form is short enough and clear enough to be used in most settings; where nested `%2` resolution may not be clear or concise enough in some cases.

```
(function(x){ return function(y){ return [x.a,y.b]; }})
```

could be written as

```
(fn [x] (fn [y] [(.x a) (.y b)]))
```

**It would be diffacult to add your own reader macro that allows nested functions** because Clojure intentionally doesn't support user defined reader macros.

Comment: Oh, that is bad. Might I ask, what is that 'mailing list'? And I couldn't see how it would be hard to implement; just add a token for nested variables. Edit: would be much to ask for a link to that proposal? Can't find it.

Comment: the official Clojure user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/clojure  the question of adding reader macros has come up too many times for me to recommend any particular thread as useful.

Answer (score 0):

As for Clojure 1.4, Clojure **does** support user-defined reader macros, which you could potentially use to define your own lambda syntax. They won't allow you to hijack the `#()` syntax, though. Get the details [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#21-reader-literals).